# woocommerce payment plugin calling web service on an custom url

Tags: php, wordpress, web-services, woocommerce

I am writing a payment plugin on woocommerce.

In checkout page,

When user type credit card number I am calling tax web service .
It is returning tax details with json.

Here is my function which I called tax web service:

```
public function bankTaxService($binNum)
  {   
     $cardNumber = $this->get_post('ccnum');
     $api = $this->api_id;

     $service = new bankTaxService();
     $response = $service->getInstallment($api, $ccnum, 100);

     return $response;
   }
```

How to write tax service json response to custom url?